# Append to a Xth dimension without specifying the dimension

Tags: python

I'm stuck figuring out how to do the following.
I have a dict `x = {}`. I also have two strings `'a/b/c/d'` and `'e/f/g'`.
In each case, I want to add values to dict x, e.g., `x[a][b][c] = 'd'` and `x[e][f] = 'g'`.

Is there a way to tell Python to figure out how deep I want to put 'd' or 'g' without having to specify a full path?

My current solution looks very ugly and I'm looking for a better way to do this.

```
x = {'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}, 'e': {'f': {}}}
s = 'a/b/c/d'.split('/')
if len(s) == 4:
    x[s[0]][s[1]][s[2]] = s[3]
elif len(s) == 3: #x[e][f] case
    x[s[0]][s[1]] = s[2]
```

Comment: There may be different ways depending on your use case. What do you need this for?

Comment: Why not just one dict with {'abc': None,'ef':None} as the keys?..

Comment: @kazemakase, I need to create full directory structure iterating over web ui links to those directories.

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj, a, b, and c can have a lot of nested dictionaries. In my case, they are directories and I can't access the file system that stores them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a for loop:

```
keys = s.split('/')
d = x
for key in keys[:-2]:
    d = d [key]
d[keys[-2]] = keys[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I want.
For s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] the result is {'c': 'd'}, but I want it to be {'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}

Comment: Nevermind my previous reply. It works like a charm! Thanks!